# How to customize Firefox's GUI using CSS?

Tags: firefox, css, stylish

The Firefox extension Stylish enables customization of a site's CSS.  I'd like to use the same extension to make some tweaks to the Firefox GUI.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to this url: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul This loads a page filled with Firefox GUI elements.
2. Open Tools-> Web Developer-> Inspector.
3. Inspect the element(s) you want to customize.  This then lets you get the IDs and classes of the various elements.
4. Create a Stylish style that modifies those elements.

Comment: One may also edit the [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) if he does not want to install Stylish. See also [userChrome.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.js).